# Differences between Django one-to-one and foreign key relationships at db level?

Tags: django, database

Is `OneToOneField` just `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`.What is the difference at db level,how about performance?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If we look to the [source code of the `OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#OneToOneField), we see:

```
class OneToOneField(ForeignKey):

    # ...

    def __init__(self, to, on_delete, to_field=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['unique'] = True
        super().__init__(to, on_delete, to_field=to_field, **kwargs)
```

It contains some extra attributes such that Django understands that the *reverse* of a `OneToOneField` is *not* a one-to-may field, but that it can thus query the for an object directly.

We thus will construct a `UNIQUE(foreign_column)` (depending on the database language the syntax can look a bit different).

For most popular database engines, at the database level, by default for a `ForeignKey`, the database constructs an *index*, to boost the performance of a *reverse lookup*. So in case you create a new row, or update an existing one, the database will check that the index does *not* contain such value (and thus uniqness is guaranteed).

This thus will for updates and creates result in an extra lookup. But the index lookup should be performed anyway when we use a `ForeignKey` (with an index), since the index is updated. Therefore on reasonable database systems, the performance difference should be negligible.